# Is there any way to export/pass a state variable to an external CSS file in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, sass

```js
const Dropdown = ({ options, selected, onSelectedChange }) => {
    const [ open, setopen ] = useState(false);


    const renderedOptions = options.map((option) => {
        if (option.value === selected.value) {
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <div key={option.value} className="item" onClick={() => onSelectedChange(option)}>
                {option.label}
            </div>
        );
    });

    return (
        <div className="ui form">
            <div className="field">
                <label className="label">Select a color</label>
                <div onClick={() => setopen(!open)} className={`ui selection dropdown ${open ? 'visible active' : ''}`}>
                    <i className="dropdown icon" />
                    <div className="text">{selected.label}</div>
                    <div className={`menu ${open ? 'visible transition' : ''}`}>{renderedOptions}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            //Here is the selected.value state (value contains string of color name
            {<div style={{ color: `${selected.value}` }}>{selected.value}</div>}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Dropdown;

const options = [
    {
        label: 'The Color Red',
        value: 'red'
    },
    {
        label: 'The Color Green',
        value: 'green'
    },
    {
        label: 'The Color Blue',
        value: 'blue'
    }
];
```

How can I use the `selected.value` in an external CSS file?

The data in the `selected.value` is a string of color name(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use Styled Components if that's what you're looking for, just an example, not really well thought out. The component can be in another file

```
const HoveredLink = styled.span`
    color: ${props => props.selected ? 'black' : 'rgb(150, 153, 156)'};
`

<HoveredLink selected={\\someconditionhere} > Hover me <HoveredLink/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it by using concept from this [URL](https://css-tricks.com/updating-a-css-variable-with-javascript/#:%7E:text=To%20update%20those%20values%20from,%2C%20e%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20root)

```
import styles from './colorchange.css';

//...

//For setting default value (and closing dropdown when clicked outside)
useEffect(() => {
        document.body.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            if (ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
                return;
            }
            setopen(false);
        });

        document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--variablename`, selected.value);
    }, []);

//...

//inside renderedoption
return (
            <div
                key={option.value}
                className="item"
                onClick={() => {
                    onSelectedChange(option);
                    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--variablename`, option.value);
                }}
            >
                {option.label}
            </div>
        );

//....
//for printing the color
<div className="colorcolor">This text is: {selected.value}</div>
```

```
CSS FILE:

 {
    --variablename: default;
}

.colorcolor {
    color: var(--variablename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use as a variable, this is not exactly CSS. So this one should work:

```
<div style={{color: selected.value}} >{ selected.label } </div>
```

You can also set style as a new variable:

```
const Dropdown = ({options,...}) => {
    const styleDiv = {
        color: options.value
    }
    //...
    return (
        //...
        <div style={styleDiv}> {options.label} </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another way using CSS stylesheet**.
Usually when I need to pass a value to use it for CSS I'll
go for specific CSS classes as I rather use the stylesheet
for style ( !== style within component ) for scalability reasons &
ease to access. If it can help ...

- **I. Known values case / no need to convert into word**
  to expect ( seems like it should be either [ blue,red,green ])

  ```html
    <div className = { selected.value } />
  ```
- **II. Need to convert into word**
  Let's say you need to change a selected.value that could be an hexadecimal value, you'll need to associate a word className you could use for CSS later on.
  *This is just an example and you can do a lot more within the expression passed*

  ```js
    // convert anticipated value to the word you need
    const colors = {'#F00': 'red', '#0F0' : green, '#00F': 'blue'};
  ```

  ```html
    <div className = { colors[ selected.value ] } />
  ```
- **Applied example**

  ```js
    import './style.css' // style.css as same level of your component

    const Dropdown = ({options,...}) => {
      // if need to make wording *(cf:. case )
      // const color = {'#F00': 'red', '#0F0' : green, '#00F': 'blue'};

      //...
      return (
          //...
          // if need to make wording *(cf:. case )
          // <div className = { colors[ selected.value ] }> { selected.value } </div> */ }
          <div className = { selected.value }> { selected.value } </div>
       )
      }
  ```

**CSS for the above cases**.

```
/*CSS file: style.css*/
.red { ...code... }
.green { ...code... }
.blue { ...code... }
```